# C++ character array not showing address

Tags: c++

I was experimenting with char array and then I tried to run this program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main ( )
{
    char *str = "Hello!" ;

    cout << &str[0] << endl ;
    cout << &str[1] << endl ;
    cout << &str[2] << endl ;
    cout << &str[3] << endl ;
    cout << &str[4] << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

And I keep getting these outputs:

```
Hello!
ello!
llo!
lo!
o!
```

What exactly is happening here? I was expecting hex values.

Comment: `char *str = "Hello";` is illegal in C++11 and deprecated before that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you take the address of an array element, you get a pointer into the array.

In `c++`, like `c`, a character array (or pointer to character) is interpreted as a string, so the characters are printed out as a string.

If you want addresses, just add a cast to `(void *)`.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std ;

int main ( )
{
    const char *str = "Hello!" ;

    cout << (void*) &str[0] << endl ;
    cout << (void*) &str[1] << endl ;
    cout << (void*) &str[2] << endl ;
    cout << (void*) &str[3] << endl ;
    cout << (void*) &str[4] << endl ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, `&str[0]` is of type `char*`, so that's a C-string as far as `cout` is concerned.

Answer (score 3):

A `char *` is assumed to be a C-style string. You need to cast to `void *` to get the pointer value.

(And you're missing a `const` - string literals are immutable.)